# inheritance in java (compile error)

Tags: java, oop

this is my program:

```
class A{
    A(int a){
    }

class B extends A{
    B(){    
    }
}

}
```

when I compile I have an error:

```
C:\Users\Public\Documents\AB.java:6: error: constructor A in class A cannot be applied to given types;
    B(){
       ^
  required: int
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

and it fixed by this change in my code:

```
    class A{
        A(int a){
        }
            A(){
        }

    class B extends A{
        B(){
        }
    }
}
```

but I don't understand why?

thanks for any help.

Comment: Read about default constructor, and also in what situation the compiler adds it to your class.

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187799/why-default-constructor-is-required-in-a-parent-class-if-it-has-an-argument-ed-c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your `A` class declares a constructor

```
A(int a){
}
```

then any code that wants to instantiate `A` needs to do so with that constructor. Something like

```
A a = new A(42);
```

You also declare a child class, `B`. Since `B` is an `A`, in addition to its constructor, it must call the parent class' constructor. This is done implicitly by the compiler. Say you had

```
class A{
    A(){
    }

class B extends A{
    B(){
        // super(); injected by compiler
    }
}
```

If you don't have a no-arg constructor, then the compiler doesn't know which constructor call to inject. You need to explicitly declare the `super(...)` call.

```
class A{
    A(int a){
    }

class B extends A{
    B(){    
        super(42);
    }
}
```

Think of it this way: you can't construct an `A` without the constructor call. When you construct a `B`, you are, through inheritance, also constructing an `A`, so you need that same constructor call.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a default constructor (no-argument) in A. The first implicit call of a constructor of any class is `super()`. But there is not `super()` method in the superclass. You can either explicitly call `super(5)` or some value, or create a default constructor in A:

```
A() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

When instance of class `B` is created a default call to `super()` constructor with no parameters is made. Each class has a default constructor with no parameters, unless a different constructor is provided explicitly.

As you have explicitly provided class `A` with a constructor that takes one parameter, it no longer has default constructor with no params, so you need to define it.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we extend a class, by default it calls super() (it has no params). In your case , it dint get the matching A() , hence it resulted in compiler error. 
Whenever u write this, what happens internally is :

```
 class A
  {
   A(int a)
   {
   }
 class B extends A
 {
   B()
   {   
    //Internally compiler calls super()
    super();//In your case, it dint get the matching constructor
   }
 }

 }
```