# Does polymorphism apply on class attributes in Java?

Tags: java, polymorphism

I know that the common use of polymorphism in OOP occurs when a parent class reference is used to refer to a child class object like this:

```
Animal animal = new Animal();
Animal dog = new Dog();
```

And I know that polymorphism applies on class methods, but does it also apply on class attribute? I tried to test that with this little example:

```
public class Main{

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Animal animal = new Animal();
        Animal dog1 = new Dog();
        Dog dog2 = new Dog();

        System.out.println("Animal object name: " + animal.name);
        System.out.println("Dog1 object name: "+dog1.name);
        System.out.println("Dog2 object name: " + dog2.name);

        animal.print();
        dog1.print();
        dog2.print();
    }

}
class Animal{
    String name = "Animal";
    public void print(){
        System.out.println("I am an: "+name);
    }
}
class Dog extends Animal{
    String name = "Dog";
    public void print(){
        System.out.println("I am a: "+name);
    }
}
```

And this is the output:

```
Animal object name: Animal
Dog1 object name: Animal
Dog2 object name: Dog
I am an: Animal
I am a: Dog
I am a: Dog
```

As you can see (I hope it's clear), the polymorphism works fine with the *print()* method, but with class attribute "name", it depends on the reference variable.

So, am I right? the polymorphism doesn't apply on class attributes?

Comment: Just FWIW, the correct term for what you're calling "class variables" is "instance fields". "Class variables" leads one to think class fields, e.g., `static` ones.

Comment: I updated the title to reflect the above suggestion. If I changed the meaning, feel free to roll it back.

Comment: "fields are not polymorphic" <- one simple rule to remember.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you extend a class, methods are overriden, but fields are hidden. Dynamic dispatch works for methods, but not for fields. Why is the language designed so, god knows why.

Comment: We know that, but we aren't gods.

Comment: The rule is you can upvote good answer and downvote bad one. Unfortunately I have no time to provide the answer, however only one answer which was downvoted is true. many upvoted answers doesn't answer the question correctly. Feel free to downvote them all, I'm still waiting, but this answer is accepted one. I don't know why OP did it but AFAIK a good answer not always an accepted one, even not highly upvoted.

Comment: You are pointed nothing, IMHO, it doesn't even close the correct answer. Either you were in a hurry or you don't know a language at all. Anyway you had a time to elaborate it, so it's already late.

Comment: You don't understand, I said 1) it doesn't provide the correct answer,2) it doesn't solve OP's problem, 3) it's lower quality.

Answer (score 8):

No, it doesn't. Instance variables are properties of a specific class, and are not affected directly by super or sub classes and polymorphism.

You can still *access* both fields by using "super.name" and "this.name" in Dog, but if you use just "name" the one in Dog will take over. If you want the other one you explicitly need to call super. Note that I'm talking about accessing the variables *in the Dog class*.

Comment: @Codebender if name is an instance variable in both Dog and Animal, and you call name in the Dog class I believe you will get the Dog's name back.

Comment: @Codebender I meant calling name inside of the Dog class, not on an instance of it. I edited that clarification in.

Comment: @CodeBender is correct, the fields are accessed from the reference class Animal(Not Dog) when using obj.name.

Comment: @RamanSB I agree s/he is correct, but I was talking about calling name from inside of the Dog class. I edited that clarification in.

Comment: You doesn't explain why it's not working on class variables.

Comment: @nikpon he didn't ask about class variables. He originally used "class variable" instead of "instance variable" but someone corrected him and he updated his question.

Comment: @Zar Someone has corrected his post, but not corrected him. Anyway in the code he is using class attributes to be correct.

Comment: @nikpon, class variables are static. He is using instance variables.

Comment: @zar variables are are variables static or not static. Instance variables are variables that hold an instance.

Comment: @nikpon, you are mixing up terminology. Class variable means that the variable is static. Instance variable means that the variable is different for each instance. See this: http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/c-cplusplus/whats-the-difference-between-a-class-variable-and-an-instance-variable/

Comment: I sneeze like this, each author uses his own terminology

Comment: @nikpon, maybe, but there is a distinct correct and incorrect terminology, as you can see in Oracle's official documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: Tutorials are also written with techno jargon. What they mean is just *instance reference" or "object reference*

Comment: @nikpon, I don't know what other source you want. Feel free to research on the topic yourself, but I am confident that I am correct. Even if you are right and the terminology varies than your justification for downvoting doesn't make sense anymore.

Comment: @Zar Strict OOP terminology defines attributes of the class regardless of language reference implementation. This terminology is taken from Smalltalk era when OOP programming is burned.

Comment: @nikpon I don't understand what you're saying or how it is relevant. If the sole reason of your downvote is that you don't believe the definition and documentation I've provided for instance vs. class variables then there is nothing left for me to do here except waste my time. I already tried giving you sources but you turned them down. As I said before, feel free to research yourself, ask a SO question, or refer to people whom you trust more. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't intend to discuss here the reason who is downvoted, I've just poited out that this answer is incorrect, but you disagree with me. So, I'm trying to make you understand that you are wrong, but you also don't understand this too, and you don't understand my comments. I think I have nothing I can add to this.

Comment: @nikpon you failed to provide me with any sources comparable to Oracle (or at all) that support your view.

Comment: I didn't intend to provide you with anything but if you need you can read JLS, originally developed by Sun Microsystems. So, it's comparable to Oracle.

Comment: @nikpon Do you mean this? Go to section 2.3: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html

Comment: 2.3. The Syntactic Grammar

Comment: @nikpon sorry, I meant 4.12.3. I'm on mobile and some of it was cut off.

Comment: Ok, they use of series buzzwords and this online reference uses it's own terminology rather than OOP terminology.

Comment: @nikpon Lol. At this point I believe that you are just unwilling to admit your mistake and learn from it. Even your own source did not support you. If that is your way of behaving when you are wrong that is fine, but please do not try to spread false information.

Comment: No, it's your mistake, I've found more correct definition of class attributes [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A-level_Computing/AQA/Problem_Solving,_Programming,_Operating_Systems,_Databases_and_Networking/Programming_Concepts/Object-oriented_programming_%28OOP%29). You said that *Instance variables are properties of a specific class* this is bull.

Comment: @nikpan you are mixing up attributes and class attributes. Every class attribute is an attribute but not every attribute is a class attribute. By that statement I am trying to say that each instance variables are specific to a class, they can't be "overridden" the same way methods are. I agree that it could be worded better though. Also please create a chat for this, I'm on mobile and don't know how to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88279/discussion-between-zar-and-nikpon).

Answer (score 5):

`Dog.name` is *hiding* `Animal.name`, and it is a **very** bad pattern to do that. Any good IDE will warn you that you're doing it.

Both instance fields do exist, and you can access both from `Dog` as `this.name` and `super.name`.

Comment: What IDE will warn what?

Comment: @nikpon I use [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/), and I know it does. I assume [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/) will as well. --- In Eclipse, the warning is called [Field declaration hides another field or variable](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fcompiler%2Fref-preferences-errors-warnings.htm)

Comment: This is only a warning to make you better code, but it's not a pattern, IMHO it's not bad if the language allows it. Otherwise it would be a bad language.

Comment: @nikpon That is so *wrong*. Just because you can do something, doesn't make it ok to do it. Take any source file, change all field and variable names to random names of 30 characters, then remove all comments and newlines from the source, so the entire file is a single line. *That's* perfectly valid, will compile and run without problems, but is still *so very wrong*.

Answer (score 5):

The field of Animal is hidden by the field of Dog, you can still access the field of Animal by referencing it as you did.

The behaviour you expect can be achieved this way:

```
public class Main{

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Animal animal = new Animal();
        Animal dog1 = new Dog();
        Dog dog2 = new Dog();

        System.out.println("Animal object name: " + animal.name);
        System.out.println("Dog1 object name: "+dog1.name);
        System.out.println("Dog2 object name: " + dog2.name);

        animal.print();
        dog1.print();
        dog2.print();
    }

}
class Animal {
    String name = "Animal";

    public void print(){
        System.out.println("I am an: "+name);
    }
}
class Dog extends Animal{
    public Dog() {
       this.name = "Dog"
    }
}
```

Comment: How adding a default constructor change anything?

Comment: Hmm, you are right. I confused it with when a non default constructor is defined in Animal. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187799/why-default-constructor-is-required-in-a-parent-class-if-it-has-an-argument-ed-c  I removed it and the update again to not clutter the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, when a parent class has a child, child class should totally looks like its parent otherwise **"How you can call them a parent and child?"** right? Anyway, child class is allowed to have a behavior different from its parent. That's quite make sense and natural.

But if you do want to override attribute from a child class you can be done it via constructor mechanism

**Code Example**

```
class Animal{
    String name;

    public Animal(){
        name = "Animal";
    }
    public Animal(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void print(){
        System.out.println("I am an: "+name);
    }
}
class Dog extends Animal{

    Dog(){
        super("Dog");
    }

    public void print(){
        System.out.println("I am a: "+name);
    }
}
```

You will see that attribute name `"Dog"` in `Dog` class is passed via constructor which here we can call constructor of parent class via a keyword `super`.

**Results:**

```
Animal object name: Animal
Dog1 object name: Dog
Dog2 object name: Dog
I am an: Animal
I am a: Dog
I am a: Dog
```

Answer (score 2):

Variables are not polymorphic in Java; they do not override one another.

**Edit:** To further support *Solver's* answer, I remember my OOP teacher claiming that when you create an *object* of `Child class` with a `reference` of `Parent class`, the *variables* in `Child class` which doesnot exist in `Parent class` are still allocated memory in the runtime but cannot be accessed as there are no methods in `Parent class` which could access a *variable* of the `Child class`.

Comment: It's not a waste of memory. Its a design aspect that allows you to interact with an object through an interface, with the ability to change that interface by referencing the object through a different type. That `Child` object could be referenced by a `Child` variable and a `Parent` variable at the same time. You could pass it to a `Child` var from the `Parent` var if casted.

Comment: Wow that was deep! Learned something new today. Edited.

Comment: How this explain why not polymorphic variables behave like polymorphic.

Comment: To add to what @Dioxin says, it is also possible to access the variables in `Child` by typecasting from a reference to `Parent`.

Answer (score 1):

When you invoke `print` method on `animal`, JVM searches for a `print` method in `dog` object first. If there were no `print` method in `dog` object, JVM would search the super class of `Dog`. Since it finds the `print` method in `Dog` class, it starts to execute it. The name field in the `Dog` class hides the name field which was inherited from the `Animal` class. Its just like:

```
public class Test {
static String name = "xyz";
public static void main(String[] args) {
    {
      String name = "abc";
      System.out.println(name); // abc is printed
    }
    System.out.println(name); // xyz is printed
}
}
```

Inside the block, there is a local variable `name`. So the global variable `name` is hidden. But when you get out of the block, the local variable comes in effect.

**NOTE:**

`Dog` class should be like:

```
class Dog extends Animal{
    this.name = "Dog";
    public void print(){
      System.out.println("I am a: " + this.name);
    }
}
```

What you did is a bad design.

Answer (score 0):

In Java we use set and get method for accessing a field. In your example, we have a Dog class extending an Animal class.

But if you declare it as an Animal, if you call directly the field `Amimal dog1 = new Dog();` you create a Dog instance, but declared as Animal, so when you call `dog1.name`, it give you the value of Animal.

Comment: Wait, what?  I'm not sure I follow here.  How does this explain what's going on?

Comment: This is correct, but what about polimorphism? Saying that a polimorfism doesn't apply on instance variables, so where is it applied?

Comment: Each programmation language have its implementation of Polymorphism ! So when you tried a solution, you need to be in accordance of  the good practices / specifications give by the language not ? Maybe, i need take more time to explain, i tried to help so ... i will improve this thanks