# Inherited subclass's class name and instance variable are not consistent with each other

Tags: java, inheritance

**Note:** Please read the question before marking it as a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32288342/does-polymorphism-apply-on-class-attributes-in-java) question. I'm quite aware of the fact that same-name fields in sub-classes are shadowed because polymorphism doesn't apply to them. My question is not specifically about it.

I have the following inheritance and same-name arguments in super and sub-classes. When printing out the `document.getLine()`'s class and `variable` they don't seem to be consistent with each other. Test prints out the following line. How is that even possible? I mean this printed out part (`Test$Line_A`) says `getLine()` is actually referencing the `Line_A` class that should mean the `variable` I'm printing out must be the one defined in `Line_A` class but it prints out `BaseLine`'s `variable`.

**My question:** Why printed out class reads `Line_A` yet `variable` references the one defined in `BaseLine`?

> Class: class Test$Line_A Variable:Base

```
public class Test {

    @org.junit.Test
    public void test(){
        Document_A document = new Document_A();
        System.out.println("Class: " + document.getLine().getClass() +" Variable:" + document.getLine().variable);
    }

    static class Document_A extends BaseDocument{
        @Override
        BaseLine getLine() {
            return new Line_A();
        }
    }

    static abstract class BaseDocument {
        abstract BaseLine getLine();
    }

    static class Line_A extends BaseLine {
        String variable = "Line_A";
    }

    static abstract class BaseLine {
        String variable = "Base";
    }
}
```

Comment: The concept you're looking for is called _shadowing_, and it's the reason why we use methods for inheritance.

Comment: Isn't it cause your `getLine()` method is returning the parent class? It's the same as using `BaseLine line = new Line_A();` in that context, so the same rules apply as what you linked. Using `getClass()` recognizes it as the child class method, but it applies the rule of variables not inheriting for your print statement when you access the variable since you're returning the object as the parent class in `getLine()`.

Answer (score 0):

Methods inherit. Fields do not.

You have a field named `variable` in `BaseLine`. You have an **utterly unrelated field**, which has absolutely no relationship whatsoever with BaseLine's `variable`, which by total coincidence is also named `variable`.

Line_A's `variable` does not override or otherwise affect or participate in a typing subrelationship with BaseLine's variable. At all.

If you think about it, if it did, that would make no sense: When you say `class Line_A extends BaseLine`, you're saying that Line_A is everything BaseLine is, and potentially more. Therefore, with that mere act, Line_a **already** has that `String variable = "base";`. There is no need to define it *again*, which is why the re-definition is treated by javac as: Oh, okay then, you want a completely new field and, hey, if you want to give it the same name as the one you inherited, fine with me.

An instance of `Line_A` therefore has *2* fields. One is named `variable`. The other one is .... also named `variable`.

Contrast this to methods. If `BaseLine` defined method `void foo() {}`, and then in `Line_A extends BaseLine` you also write `void foo() {}`, then there is only one method, and Line_A's method is merely overriding the one in BaseLine.

Fields do not work that way and cannot be made to work that way.

### Solution 1

Just  get rid of the field declaration in Line_A, entirely. You can override that field in Line_A, in e.g. a constructor:

```
class LineA extends BaseLine {
    LineA() {
        this.variable = "A";
    }
}
```

Yes, still 'this' - `variable` (defined in BaseLine.java) is still a field of **`this`** object.

### Solution 2

Use methods:

```
public class Baseline {
    public String getVariableName() {
        return "Base";
    }
}

class LineA extends Baseline {
    @Override public String getVariableName() {
        return "A";
    }
}

Baseline bl = new LineA();
System.out.println(bl.getVariableName()); // prints 'A'
```