# error while creating the Parent object inside child class

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I have two class :-

```
import java.lang.*;
class A {
    public A(int number) {
        System.out.println("HI I AM INSIDE PARENT CONSTRUCTOR");
    }
}
class B extends A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A obj = new A(10);
    }
}
```

Error:- Implicit super constructor A() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor.

Comment: When asking for help, please take the time to format and indent your code reasonably and readably. (It's a good idea when not asking for help, too.) *(I've done it for you this time.)*

Comment: Note that there's no point to `import java.lang.*;` That's imported by default.

Comment: Usually an IDE like Eclipse or others, give you a hint about that kind of errors if you move the mouse over the compilation error

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have no constructor declared in `B`, so the compiler is supplying the default constructor, which in effect looks like this:

```
B() {
    super();
}
```

Since `A` has no constructor accepting zero parameters, `B` can't be compiled. You'll need to add a constructor to `B` that calls `super(int)`, or you'll need to add a zero-parameters constructor to `A`.

Comment: Can you please explain Why it is calling B's constructor.While creation of the Parent class Object.

Comment: @shankarDayalupadhyay: It isn't. You're not getting that far. The code doesn't *compile*. You can't run code until it compiles. If you add a `B` constructor taking an `int` that calls `super(int)`, the code will compile. When you run it, since you never create an instance of `B`, that constructor will never be run (just the `A` constructor).

Answer (score 2):

**Principle**

A subclass constructor has to invoke the parent constructor.

By default, a no arg constructor is generated by the compiler if you don't declare one.
Important detail : this generated constructor invokes the parent constructor with a no arg invocation.

---

**Your case**

You don't declare a constructor in B. 
So a default no arg constructor of B is generated :

This constructor is :

```
B(){
   super();
}
```

but it cannot invoke the parent constructor as it declares one parameter :

```
 public A(int number)
```

So the compiler emits this error :

> Implicit super constructor A() is undefined for default constructor.
>   Must define an explicit constructor.

To solve your problem, declare a constructor in the subclass that invokes explicitly the parent constructor with the expected argument :

```
public B(int number) {
   super(number);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing the `default constructor` in your `A` class.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187799/why-default-constructor-is-required-in-a-parent-class-if-it-has-an-argument-ed-c) for further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You have given your own constructor for A having arguments of int. now you need to add a constructor on your own to the class B as well.

```
public B(int number) {
   super(number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add constructor B(int):

```
import java.lang.*;

class A {
    public A(int number) {
        System.out.println("HI I AM INSIDE PARENT CONSTRUCTOR");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public B(int number) { 
        super(number);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A obj = new A(10);
    }
}
```

Add:

```
public B(int number) { 
    super(number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you don't define a constructor in Java, you get an implicit default constructor. When you define a constructor, then the default constructor is not there anymore. So, when you have something like:

```
Class A {

}
```

this is equivalent to:

```
Class A {
    A() {
        super();
    }
}
```

In your case, class B is calling the default constructor of A, but because A already defined another constructor, the default constructor is then not there anymore, unless you define it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Cause you have defined a constructor with arguments in parent class,so the compiler won't call the default constructor without arguments.In order to instance parent class before subclass  initializing,you have to call parent's explicit  constructor in subclass.