# Abstract parameter constructors

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, abstract

I want to defer common setup logic to an abstract class. The common setup logic is parameterized. I took a swing at it and made an abstract constructor:

```
public abstract class CondimentDecorator extends Beverage {
  protected Beverage beverage;

  public CondimentDecorator(Beverage beverage) {
    this.beverage = beverage;
  }
...
```

The concrete impl of the class above then looks something like this:

```
public class Soy extends CondimentDecorator {

public String getDescription() {
  return beverage.getDescription() + ", Soy";
}
....
```

This does not compile. I get:

```
public class Soy extends CondimentDecorator {
   ^
required: Beverage
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Adding a constructor that accepts a Beverage and calls super(beverage) makes this compile. My question is:

Why can't Java see at compile time that I am perfectly happy with the superclass's constructor and writing `public ConcreteClass(Beverage bev) {super(bev)}` is a waste of time?

Bonus points for showing me a way to accomplish this :)

**Edit**: It was suggested this was a duplicate of [Why default constructor is required in a parent class if it has an argument-ed constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187799/why-default-constructor-is-required-in-a-parent-class-if-it-has-an-argument-ed-c)
The relevant part is this:

> If you don't specify a constructor explicitly (as in B) the Java compiler will create a parameterless constructor for you like this:

```
B()
{
    super();
}
```

Thank you for pointing this out. Even though that question does shed light on what actually happens with *no-arg* constructors, this one is certainly not a duplicate. 
I am still sitting here thinking: Why can't the java compiler see that the parent class already has an arg constructor and generate one for the child class in a similar fashion as it does for the no-arg ones?
Does it really not seem like a swell language feature?

Comment: Personally, I like an expilcit coding style, and I'm happily spending the 5 seconds to have Eclipse generate the constructor you want. Seeing a `new ConcreteClass(beverage)` then directly points me to the definition of this constructor, while your suggestion leaves me searching up the hierarchy for the effective definition.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree with you on explicit coding style. However, I think you are just as quick to look at a class, see it has *no* constructor then go up the hierarchy as you are seeing it *has* a constructor thats simply super()

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a 1 argument constructor for your superclass. You don't have a non-argument constructor like so:

```
public CondimentDecorator() {// do something}
```

As your Soy class inherits the CondimentDecorator constructor by default, it will only inherit the one with an argument (hence warning for no arguments). You will need to manually provide a non-argument constructor like I have shown above to make your code compile.

Comment: You dont have to provide a constructor with no arguments, in his situation he probably doesnt want that.

Answer (score 0):

Java by default give you a `default constructor` (without argument)...But when you add any new constructor, this default one will disappear.
So, the only way to initialize your super class is to call your own constructor.
And your subclass should call your superclass's constructor first (to initialize superclass's fields and so on) and then its fields...